Largest value in database
I'm looking for the SQL query that returns a list of the top 5 largest values in the database. Something like SELECT TOP(5) * FROM Database
The result would be:
table_name |  column_name | field_max_length

Exercise is to find the field that causes the issue exceeding the size of max data which can be loaded into Excel from SQL Server to sort below issue:

Memory error: A record (66341 bytes) was encountered that exceeds the maximum page size of the storage object (65528 bytes)

Just to clarify I'm looking for a needle in the haystack. The longest value in the cell in a database across 100 tables which is causing the above error.

What do you define "largest" to be? Characters? Bytes Size? Some other arbitrary definition? Honestly, though, this sounds like an XY Problem. Why do you need to do this?

SELECT  TOP 10 OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) TableName, st.row_count FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st WHERE index_id < 2 ORDER BY st.row_count DESC might get you started

I did mention the text memory issue I'm looking to find plus it doesn't matter if it is bytes or chars since I need the largest value. Whatever is more convenient.

thank you @GuidoG its good for one table but I have over 100 that are used in SSAS and then in Excel as a result.  Worst case Ill need to run above for all of them.

Sounds like the real problem is you're trying to put very long string/binary values into Excel. Why are you doing that in the first place? Excel isn't the place to store such values.

It is a part of SSAS tabular model which is being used with static data provided by the user. This error doesn't appear in PowerBI just in Excel. Inherited solution.

It is probably not a single value that is too large (takes up too many bytes) , but the combination of values that make up the problem record

This will work in SQL server 2017+. If you are on 2016- then you'll need to use multiple sub queries with the "old" FOR XML PATH method.(I'm not doing that; 2016 is only in extended support, 2014 almost End of Life, and 2012 and prior are end of life. If you are using such an old version, it's likely time to upgrade.)
This "works" by creating a massive dynamic statement, getting the max data length of each column from the table, then unpivoting them, inserting all that unpivoted data into a (temporary) table, and finally getting the TOP (5). It should be safe any names that require delimit identifying. If you have deprecated data types (like text), it may error; you'll have to omit those columns if so.
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delimiter nchar(3) = N',' + @CRLF;
WITH Statements AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'') + --Force to MAX
           N'WITH DataLengths AS(' + @CRLF +
           N'    SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(s.name,'''') + N' AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
           N'           N' + QUOTENAME(t.name,'''') + N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF +
           STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'') + --Force to MAX
                      N'           MAX(DATALENGTH(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N')) AS ' + QUOTENAME(c.name),@Delimiter) + @CRLF +
           N'    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N')' + @CRLF +
           N'SELECT DL.SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       DL.TableName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       V.ColumnName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       V.MaxColumnLength' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM DataLengths DL' + @CRLF +
           N'     CROSS APPLY(VALUES' + @CRLF +
           STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'') + --Force to MAX
                      N'                       (N' + QUOTENAME(c.name,'''') + N',DL.' +  QUOTENAME(c.name) + N')',@Delimiter) + N')V(ColumnName,MaxColumnLength);' AS Statement
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
         JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    GROUP BY s.name,
             t.name)
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(Statement,@CRLF)
FROM Statements;

--PRINT @SQL; --Uncomment to see the first 4,000 bytes of the statement

CREATE TABLE #DataLengths (SchemaName sysname,
                           TableName sysname,
                           ColumnName sysname,
                           MaxColumnLength bigint);
INSERT INTO #DataLengths (SchemaName,TableName,ColumnName,MaxColumnLength)
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT TOP(5)
       SchemaName,
       TableName,
       ColumnName,
       MaxColumnLength
FROM #DataLengths
ORDER BY MaxColumnLength DESC;

DROP TABLE #DataLengths;

